# Can't install additional printer 32-bit drivers on Windows 7 64-bit I get the error “Selected printer driver not found”, what should I do?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, printer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When installing additional printer 32-bit drivers fails on Windows 7 64-bit I get the error “Selected printer driver not found”, what should I do?](https://superuser.com/questions/23703/when-installing-additional-printer-32-bit-drivers-fails-on-windows-7-64-bit-i-get)

I've successfully installed Windows 7 (x64) and drivers for my HP Color LaserJet 2600n, and have no problem printing with this setup.

There is another PC in the network running XP SP3, and I want to share the printer so that users of that PC can also print.

On W7 I have the option of installing additional printer drivers for other system architectures (Itanium and x86). I've downloaded the most current 32-bit drivers for the printer, but every time I direct the install dialog to the folder containing the drivers, I get the following error message:

```
Selected printer driver not found

The specified location does not contain the driver for the requested processor architecture.

Retry Cancel
```

I'm stumped. I'm absolutely certain that the specified location actually does contain the correct drivers; I've even installed them on the XP system.

I've tried everything I can think of. What am I overlooking?

Comment: The long and short of it (covered in the dupe I suggested) is you have to ensure that both the 32-bit and 64-drivers refer to the printer by the same name/model, so that Windows can associate them to the same printer.  So if you haven't already, go get the latest printer driver from HP for both bit-levels; you may have better luck with this by using the HP Universal Print Driver (if it supports that printer).

Answer (score 0):

Windows needs a **inf** file to read to install the drivers.

Often I just keep clicking through the directories til I find it.  If that isn't possible and the printer requires a proprietary installer, there is an alternative.

`http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732946.aspx`

This specific articles involves installing the drivers on an x86 OS, like on XP mode and then using **Print Management** to upload them onto the print server, which would be your WIn7 machine.